# error in android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, user-permissions

My issue is that I can't use Write or Read EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permissions in my app and my device has android Version Marshmallow.

I use

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddServiceActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

or

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2909);
            }

        }
```

as well but app still crashes.

If any one any solution regarding this please help me out of it..

Sorry for my English and thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the crash log.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33163206/3395198

Comment: Process: com.bindaspunch.my.bindaspunch, PID: 31921                                              java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=31921, uid=10119 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()      This is my Crash log

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya   Sir i use this code too.. but still there is crashes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431723/read-external-storage-permission-for-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599132/securityexception-permission-denial-reading-only-on-emulator

Comment: Sir very sorry to say that, these code not run in my case too

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya      SIr basically my code is about to get image from camera and gallery and put it on imageview but it crases all time on permission issue...

Comment: sir if you have any other solution , kindly help me out...

Comment: @GouravSharma Faced same problem .Make sure ,did you add manifest permission there ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350941/android-read-external-storage-permission-not-working

Comment: yes sir i add permission in manifest too...

Comment: @GouravSharma facing this problem yet ?

Comment: yes sir not solved yet

Comment: i not run my get image from camera or gallery code due to this permission denied issue